# XPath following-sibling get text from <td>

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

Via `XPath`, I'm trying get the text value located in the second `<td>` (text: `0.56`) by specifically using `following-sibling` and a keyword (`. = 'Vitamin D'`).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <td><a href="http://website.com/12345.php">Vitamin D</a></td>
        <td>0.56</td>
        <td>µg</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far, I have managed to identify the text in the first `<td>` by its link content through:

`//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://website.com/') and . = 'Vitamin D']`

---

I have tried this and other alternatives, but I'm not getting it right:

`//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://website.com/') and . = 'Vitamin D']/following-sibling::td`

and

`//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://website.com/') and . = 'Vitamin D']following-sibling::text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following sibling on the `td`, i.e. `//td[a[starts-with(@href, 'http://website.com/') and . = 'Vitamin D']]/following-sibling::td[1]`.

Comment: Thanks! So the issue was that `//td` was needed in front to initiate, and then to "capture" with `[1]`?

Comment: The `<td>0.56</td>` is the first `td` sibling of the `td` with the link, it is not a sibling of the `a` link element. So you need to select the `td` containing the link (the `a` element) and then select the first following-sibling::td, as without the positional predicate `[1]` you would select all three following sibling `td` elements.